# Slide div left/right using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I found following code in multiple places to slide left/right:

```
$('#hello').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
```

However, i can't get it working. Here is minimalistic test which I am trying:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en-us">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#test").click(function() {
            $('#hello').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
        });
    });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <article >
        <div id="hello">
            Hello       
        </div>
        <p><span id="test">Test</span>
    </arcticle>
</body>
```

I tried it in Chrome and Safari and it doesn't work.

What is the problem? Are there other working methods to slide left/right?

Comment: [That's because Slide is part of the jQuery UI Effects.](http://jqueryui.com/effect/)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`$('#hello').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);` requires the jQuery-ui library. See http://www.jqueryui.com

Answer (score 69):

You can easy get that effect without using jQueryUI, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slide').click(function(){
    var hidden = $('.hidden');
    if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden.animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    } else {
        hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
    }
    });
});
```

Try this working Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZQTFq/

Comment: I don't think this is the cleanest way to do this but t worked like a charm. However, I needed to set `overflow-x: hidden;`

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do so is using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) animation library.
**Javascript**

```
/* --- Show DIV --- */
$( '.example' ).removeClass( 'fadeOutRight' ).show().addClass( 'fadeInRight' );

/* --- Hide DIV --- */
$( '.example' ).removeClass( 'fadeInRight' ).addClass( 'fadeOutRight' );
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="example">Some text over here.</div>
```

Easy enough to implement. Just don't forget to include the animate.css file in the header :)

Comment: Bravo! Animate.css along with JQuery is a super clean and simple way of animating.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#left").on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#left').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500, function () {
            $('#right').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
        });
    });
    $("#right").on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#right').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500, function () {
            $('#left').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
        });
    });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div style="height:100%;width:100%;background:cyan" id="left">
<h1>Hello im going left to hide and will comeback from left to show</h1>
</div>
<div style="height:100%;width:100%;background:blue;display:none" id="right">
<h1>Hello im coming from right to sho and will go back to right to hide</h1>
</div>
```

```
$("#btnOpenEditing").off('click');
$("#btnOpenEditing").on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mappingModel').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500, function () {
        $('#fsEditWindow').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
    });
});
```

It will work like charm take a look at the demo.