# navigation slide in issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make this navigation for a website, and it seems to work now, i just cant get the right animation. I have tried to use animate, but i could not make it work and im not sure if thats even the best way to go arround it.

I want my menus to slide in from the side they live in - not scale down from the top corner as the standard .show / .hide does.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="nav">
        <a href="#" class="nav-show">menu</a>
        <a href="#" class="search-show">search</a>

        <div class="nav-wrap">
            <ul>
                <li><a herf="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="search-wrap">
            <ul>
                <li><a herf="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {background-color:#567;}
* {margin:0; padding:0;}
ul, li {margin:0; padding:0;}

.wrapper {width:100%; height:60px; background-color:#333;}
.nav {width:100%; height:60px;}
.nav-show {width:60px; background-color:#666; color:#FFF; display:inline-block; height:100%; line-height:60px; text-align:center;}
.search-show {width:60px; background-color:#666; color:#FFF; display:inline-block; height:100%; line-height:60px; text-align:center; float:right;}

.nav-wrap {width:90%; background-color:#999; color:#000;padding:10px; display:none; position:fixed; top:60px; left:0; bottom:0; overflow:auto;}
.nav-wrap ul {list-style:none; background-color:#F60;}
.nav-wrap ul li {height:60px; width:100%; background-color:#CCC;margin-bottom:5px;}

.search-wrap {width:90%; background-color:#999; color:#000;padding:10px; display:none; position:fixed; top:60px; right:0; bottom:0; overflow:auto;}
.search-wrap ul {list-style:none; background-color:#F60;}
.search-wrap ul li {height:60px; width:100%; background-color:#CCC;margin-bottom:5px;}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $(".nav-show").click(function () {
            $(".search-wrap").hide("slow");
            $(".nav-wrap").toggle("slow");
        });

        $(".search-show").click(function () {
            $(".nav-wrap").hide("slow");
            $(".search-wrap").toggle("slow");
        });
    });
```

i also made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iBertel/cK9UM/27/)

i know my jquery code is not the best, im rather rookie here, so if it can be done smarter, i would love to see it. Maybe it would be better to just use CSS3 for animation?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823305/slide-div-left-right-using-jquery

Comment: ahh looks like I read it wrong I was thinking you wanted it to slide down now from the left, but yes YaMo's link will get you that using the second answer without requiring jQuery UI

Comment: But i need to have width of 90% and not a fixed width - then this example wont work will it?

Comment: The easing plugin creates a nice effect if you want to use it http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/cK9UM/29/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with easing plugin, looks great:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/cK9UM/29/)**

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $(".nav-show").click(function () {
            $(".search-wrap").hide("slow");
            $(".nav-wrap").toggle('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000, "easeOutExpo");
        });

        $(".search-show").click(function () {
            $(".nav-wrap").hide("slow");
            $(".search-wrap").toggle('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000, "easeOutExpo");
        });
    });
```

Comment: no, just remove , "easeOutExpo" if you don't want the easing ;)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it per your needs

new [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cK9UM/33/)

HTML:

```
<div class="nav-wrap hidden">
            <ul>
                <li><a herf="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="search-wrap hidden">
            <ul>
                <li><a herf="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a herf="#">4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $(".nav-show").click(function () {
        $(".search-wrap").hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
        $(".search-wrap").addClass("hidden");
        if($(".nav-wrap").hasClass('hidden')){
            $(".nav-wrap").show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
            $(".nav-wrap").removeClass("hidden");
        } else {
            $(".nav-wrap").addClass("hidden");
            $(".nav-wrap").hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000)
        }
    });

    $(".search-show").click(function () {
        $(".nav-wrap").hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
        $(".nav-wrap").addClass("hidden");
        $(".search-wrap").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);

        if($(".search-wrap").hasClass('hidden')){
            $(".search-wrap").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
            $(".search-wrap").removeClass("hidden");
        } else {
            $(".search-wrap").addClass("hidden");
            $(".search-wrap").hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000)
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Yea but i want it to slide-in from the sides not the top though... Sorry if i didnt make that clear.

Comment: thank you, but i will go with the last one because of the small amount of code needed.