# Make div appear sliding left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've set a div to be `$('#myDiv').css('visibility', 'hidden');`. My question is, How do I make it appear sliding left to right?

This is what I tried but I need to make it slide left to right.

```
if($('#myDiv').css('visibility') == 'hidden'){
    $('#myDiv').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('#myDiv').slideDown('slow');
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using jQuery UI https://jqueryui.com/toggle/

Comment: @mcgrailm thanks. But I need the DIV to slide one time only. So once it slides I need it to be visible until the user exit the page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823305/slide-div-left-right-using-jquery

Comment: @NagarajS thanks. I did come across that while googling. But I didn't know how to combine it with my`.css('visibility', 'visible')` method.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution for you:

I can use each function seperatly, depending on what you need: I used toggle 2 times.

The HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        Place your content here
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#container{
   width:0px;
   overflow-x:hidden;
   display:none;
   background-color:blue;
   color:white;
}
```

The javascript / jQuery:

```
function show(el, width, speed, callback){
    $(el).css({"display":"block"});
    $(el).animate({"width":width}, speed, callback);
}

function hide(el, speed, callback){
    $(el).animate({"width":"0px"}, speed, function(){        
        $(el).css({"display":"none"});
        callback();
    });
}

function toggle(el, width, speed, callback){
    console.log($(el).css("width"));
    if($(el).css("width")== "0px")
        show(el,width, speed, callback);
    else
        hide(el, speed, callback);
}

toggle("#container", "150px", 500, null);
setTimeout(function(){toggle("#container", "150px", 500, null);}, 2000);
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/195yz674/3/