# JQuery: Trouble with hide() and show() slide effect

Tags: jquery

On my page I've been trying to have one div slide out of view when it's clicked and another to slide in and vice versa. My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('#trialForm').hide();

    $('#trialClick').click(function () {
        $(this).hide('slide');
        $('#trialForm').show('slide');
    });

    $('#trialForm').click(function () {
        $(this).hide('slide');
        $('#trialClick').show('slide');
    });

    $('.clickHere form input').click(false);
});
```

It seems to work pretty much perfectly. One div phases in and the other out, but it's definitely not a slide. Moreover, whichever effect I put in place of 'slide' just produces the same animation. Any advice would be appreciated as I'm completely stumped.

Thanks,

Stuart

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mcara_01/12pe3fp5/1/

So what I'm looking for is for the first div to slide out to the left and the second one to slide in from the right, if that makes any sense?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slide div left/right using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823305/slide-div-left-right-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a string to a hide/show function on single parameter. But you can pass time duration in seconds. Or you can use slide toggle this will give the animation effect.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('#trialForm').hide();

    $('#trialClick').click(function () {
        $(this).slideToggle(300);
        $('#trialForm').slideToggle(300);
    });

    $('#trialForm').click(function () {
        $(this).slideToggle(300);
        $('#trialClick').slideToggle(300);
    });

    $('.clickHere form input').click(false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, slideToggle gives the sort of effect I'm after, just I'm looking for a horizontal slide. So the first div would slide out to the left and the second will simultaneously slide in from the right.

Comment: If you want slide from left-to-right/right-to-left you need to use juery-ui http://www.jqueryui.com or if you dont want to use jquery-ui you can use .animate() and set width 0 and vice versa, then hide.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. I settled for jquery UI and it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the signature of the according jQuery [methods](http://api.jquery.com/show/). If you provide a single string parameter, it's supposed to be a duration keyword. If you want another animation, you need to pass an object instead.

Instead of using `show`, you perhaps try another jquery effect, which each have their own [method](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) like `fade()` or `slide()`.

Also, nowadays I would prefer doing this with css instead. I did a fiddle a while ago to play with css transitions to create a menu: http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/p2g31147/

Comment: Interesting pointer. I'm a bit of a novice and I was completely unaware css could be used for this sort of thing.

Comment: @StuartMcAra have a look at the MDN articles about [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) and [keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) if you like to dig deeper. However, where you able to solve your initial problem? Do you need additional help/advice?

Comment: Thank you, yes I managed with jquery UI for now. I appreciate the help, I'll be looking into those transitions right away.

Comment: Glad, that we could help you:) If your problem is solved, consider accepting one of the answer which you think helped you most. Additionally, you can upvote as many answers as you like. This gives reputation points to you (and the people who answered) and indicates to the SO community that your question was solved.

Answer (score 0):

try to use css transitions to make effect work.
Example : http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-slide.php
set class to element via $(#elementId).toggleClass("closed")