# Smooth move to next div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to show next videos div which is hidden with smooth move. Jquery .hide() or .show() function with time it does not produce expected output. I want to show with smooth move.

Here is my source code:

**html:**

```
<div class="video_wrapper">
            <div class="videos visible">
                <div class="video_content"></div>
                <div class="video_content"></div>
                <div class="video_content"></div>
                <div class="video_content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="videos">
                <div class="video_content"></div>
                <div class="video_content"></div>
                <div class="video_content"></div>
                <div class="video_content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="videos">
                <div class="video_content"></div>
                <div class="video_content"></div>
                <div class="video_content"></div>
                <div class="video_content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
        <div class="pre_element">&lang;</div>
        <div class="next_element">&rang;</div>
    </div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
 $(".next_element").click(function() {
            //Show previous button
            $('.pre_element').show();
            //Find the element that's currently showing
            $showing = $('.video_wrapper .videos.visible').first();
            //Find the next element
            $next = $showing.next();
            //Change which div is showing
            $showing.removeClass("visible").hide();
            $next.addClass("visible").show(200);
            //If there's no more elements, hide the NEXT button
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to slide horizontally, than you should use [horizon-swiper](http://horizon-swiper.sebsauer.de/).

 Or
You can use Hide with slide effect (Checkout answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14823328/3599251)) from JQuery UI.